# Display and query images in grafana

Tags: php, grafana, influxdb

I am trying to develop a tool to display images omn grafana (5.3.1) . The images are regularly generated from a camera and stored on a server in different folders according to the acquisition time (yyyy\dd\mm). I mounted a shared disk on my computer and I have access to the images and the path to the images is for example:

**Z:\images\2019\03\06\2019-03-06_100000.bmp**

Now, I would like to be able to scroll the images from grafana based on their timestamp. So far I tried the following steps:

1. Stored on a influx database the path of the images and their timestamps as they were generated.
2. Installed AJAX plugin in grafana and tried to configure iframe to get at least on sample image.

But I am facing several challenges also due to my poor skills in programming:

- I cannot display images outside grafana "public" folder
- I don't know how to dynamically change the displayed images according to the time range selected.

It would be great if I could see the thumbnails of the available images like on an image gallery based on the selected time range and displaying the full image on a different portion of the screen keeping the other thumbnails.

I have tried to implement this in php (see attached picture) but I would like to do this on grafana or at least ask the experts if this is feasable.
I would really appreciate your help or at least some hints to point me in the right direction and I hope I expressed my problem in a clear way, otherwise I would be happy to provide more details.

Thanks a lot in advance.
Jay

[example of displaying tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eUIA.png)